# PHPExcel Codeigniter : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception'

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, fatal-error

I am working on a project in which i need to import data form a excel(`.xlsx`) file
into a table in database. 
I already write code for a controller `upload.php`

```
    $this->load->library('excel');


    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');


    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');



    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);



    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitcoinreports/uploads/data.xlsx';


    $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load($path);


    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    //loop from first data until last data

    for($i=2; $i<=77; $i++){
    $name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
    $email = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
    $phone = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();
    $details = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue();   
    $location = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();
    $data_user = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $email ,
    "phone" => $phone ,
    "details" => $details ,
    "location" => $location ,
    );
    $this->dashboard_model->add_data($data_user);
  }
```

Whenever i call this controller i got the following error

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open C:/xampp/htdocs/bitcoinreports/uploads/data.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:347
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\application\controllers\admin\upload.php(40): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
#1 [internal function]: Upload->index()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\index.php(202): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 347
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: So clear error.. your file data.xlsx doesn't exists at the path you have set  or its not accessable.. Both are possibles as I see that its inside your windows C: ..

Answer (score 0):

Before opening the file, check if it exists, AND is readable for the process that runs PHP (xampp in this case. Not sure how the user is named in xampp, maybe apache).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

is_readable — Tells whether a file exists and is readable

So replace this:

```
$objPHPExcel=$objReader->load($path);
```

with

```
if (is_readable($path)){
  $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load($path);
} else {
  // handle problem, for example
  echo "cannot read $path";
  exit;
}
```